# AngularJS scope not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, indexeddb, digest

After executing get or put in indexeddb, the callback is updating the scope.
The problem is, no update is being triggered in the ui!

A common solution is to use apply or digest but that is wrong, you should **NOT** use those operations. Angular should update it automatically.

Now my guess, after reading some stuff, is that the callback is being executed in a different context, outside of the scope.

My question is basically: how can I execute an indexeddb callback in an angularjs scope context?

**EDIT:**
A rough look on how its built:

```
GetObjectStoreData(iDb, objectStore, function (res) {
    $scope.result = res;
}
```

The call is made from inside the scope so the scope is used in the callback. The callback parameter is the contents of the object store

Comment: Please include some code.  It's really hard to figure out what's wrong with out it.

Answer (score 1):

You asserted that you should not have to use `Scope.$apply` because AngularJS should do it for you.

This is true only for callbacks managed by Angular. For example, when you use `$timeout` in place of `window.setTimeout`, angular wraps your provided callback in a call to `Scope.$apply`, causing a digest cycle to run once your callback completes. If you interact directly with browser APIs rather than calling through AngularJS, it is *your* responsibility to call `Scope.$apply` at the appropriate time.

If you don't want to manage the scope directly, you could instead use a wrapper library like [angular-indexedDB](https://github.com/bramski/angular-indexedDB), which (amongst other things) handles the scope notifications when callbacks occur.